# Why am I getting a Null Pointer Exception when adding to an initialized ArrayList in a Kotlin Android project?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I am using an arraylist of a custom data class to pass values to my adapter for a recycler view. My thought process is that I initialized the public arraylist in the onCreate method so I can use `.add` to add to it in a later method.
My idea is to have `initializedDbTables` populate the arraylist before passing that arraylist to the adapter. However, when I use `.add` it get a NPE. onCreate is definitely called before anything else so I am not sure I understand why adding is causing the NPE. Maybe it has something to do with the data class? Any help would be appreciated...

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CategoryAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    lateinit var categoryModelArrayList: ArrayList<CategoryModel>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        supportActionBar?.hide()//hide the stupid default title
        recyclerView= findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycle_card)
        categoryModelArrayList = ArrayList<CategoryModel>()

        initializeDbTables() // populate arraylist for cards
        val categoryAdapter = CategoryAdapter(this, categoryModelArrayList, this)
...
}
private fun initializeDbTables(){
        var dbHelper: MyDatabaseHelper = MyDatabaseHelper(this)
        val db = dbHelper.readableDatabase
        //check if date is initialized
        var cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM current_date_table", null)
        var row_count = 0
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            row_count = cursor.getInt(0)
        }
        Log.i("initializeDTables","Row count for date table is $row_count" )
        if( row_count == 0){// insert date if it isnt already there
            val currentDate = LocalDate.now()
            val contentValues = ContentValues()
            contentValues.put("month",currentDate.month.value )
            contentValues.put("year",currentDate.year )
            Log.i("DB","Writing the current date to db" )
            writeToDatabase(contentValues, "current_date_table")
        }
        //do we have a total row?
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM budget_table", null)
        row_count = 0
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            row_count = cursor.getInt(0)
        }
        Log.i("initializeDTables","Row count for budget table is $row_count" )
        if( row_count == 0){
            val contentValues = ContentValues()
            contentValues.put("category","overall")
            contentValues.put("total",0.0)
            contentValues.put("spent",0.0)
            contentValues.put("percent",0)
            writeToDatabase(contentValues, "budget_table")
        }
        //load values into adapter for recycler view (list of card layouts)
        Log.i("initDbTables", "err next line?")
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM budget_table where _id > 1", null)//id 1 should always be total and anything greater will be in the recycle view.
        Log.i("initDbTables", "err prev  line?")
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Log.i("initDbTables", "err cursor  line?")
            val category = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("category"))
            val spent = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("spent"))
            val total =  cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("total"))
            val percent = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("percent"))
            categoryModelArrayList.add(CategoryModel(category, spent, total, percent))
        Log.i("initDbTables", "err previous  line?")
        }
        Log.i("initDbTables", "err prev line2 ?")
        cursor.close()
            db.close()
        Log.i("initDbTables", "err prev line?3")

    }
...
}//class
```

```
data class CategoryModel(var category: String, var spent: Double, var total: Double, var percent: Int)
```

stacktrace:

```
2024-01-19 11:33:02.998 11198-11198 onCreate                com.styio.budgetbuddy3               I  Checking if Db has values...
2024-01-19 11:33:03.013 11198-11198 initializeDTables       com.styio.budgetbuddy3               I  Row count for date table is 1
2024-01-19 11:33:03.014 11198-11198 initializeDTables       com.styio.budgetbuddy3               I  Row count for budget table is 3
2024-01-19 11:33:03.014 11198-11198 initDbTables            com.styio.budgetbuddy3               I  err next line?
2024-01-19 11:33:03.014 11198-11198 initDbTables            com.styio.budgetbuddy3               I  err prev  line?
2024-01-19 11:33:03.016 11198-11198 initDbTables            com.styio.budgetbuddy3               I  err cursor  line?
2024-01-19 11:33:03.018 11198-11198 AndroidRuntime          com.styio.budgetbuddy3               D  Shutting down VM
2024-01-19 11:33:03.022 11198-11198 AndroidRuntime          com.styio.budgetbuddy3               E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.styio.budgetbuddy3, PID: 11198
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.styio.budgetbuddy3/com.styio.budgetbuddy3.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                                        at com.styio.budgetbuddy3.MainActivity.initializeDbTables(MainActivity.kt:125)
                                                                                                        at com.styio.budgetbuddy3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:42)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```

I have tried initializing the variable categoryModelArrayList without making it lateinit with no luck. I have made it public and private with no luck as well.

Comment: If you failed to initialize `categoryModelArrayList` before accessing it you'd be getting an `UninitializedPropertyAccessException`, and not a `NullPointerException`. Are you sure line 125 corresponds with the `categoryModelArrayList.add` call, and not with one of the `cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow()` calls above it?

Comment: Thanks for the response. That is a good point. I just tested, and it definitely gets past those lines. I even added a check to see if categoryModelArrayList is null and it is not...
Could it have something to do with the initializeDbTables function being private?

Comment: No, it has to do with it being null.

Comment: `Could it have something to do with the initializeDbTables function being private?` - I highly doubt it.